# A doxygen eclipse plugIn automatically generating stub documentation?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, documentation, doxygen

I'am looking for an eclipse-plugin for doxygen code documentation. I have found the eclox-plugIn ( http://home.gna.org/eclox/ ). I would like find out, how can it automatically generate a "empty" doxygen comment, which could be filled out later or what is the better choice for a documentation eclipse plugIn?

For example for a function: void f(int p1, int p2, ...), it should generate:

```
/*! \brief ...
    \param p1 ...
    ..
*/
```

PS
I'm using for mainly the c/c++ languages

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See **[updated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590019/2436175)**.

---

**Old answer:**
In eclipse helios in ***window***->***preferences*** you can do:
***c/c++***->***Code Style***->***Code Templates***->***Comments***
+
Automatically add comments for new methods and classes

You can configure the comment style here, but it is not as smart as it should be. If you find something better, I would be very happy...

Comment: Hi , I tried that , but does not seem to genrate the comment ... is there something i am missing ..

Comment: It's only for generated code... See my new answer.

Comment: For anyone who come looking for how to integrate eclox in eclipse, see https://github.com/theolind/mahm3lib/wiki/Integrating-Doxygen-with-Eclipse

Comment: Can Doxagen plugin be customized? For example, I'd like it to generate `@brief` keyword when adding function comment.

Answer (score 94):

A different (better) approach than my previous answer:
In Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor,
In the right tab look for "Documentation tool comments", and in "Workspace default" set `doxygen`.

Now you can type `/**` above a function and press return.

```
/**
int foo(int bar);
```

becomes

```
/**
 * 
 * @param bar
 * @return
 */
int foo(int bar);
```

Comment: Exactly the switch I was looking for as well.  Cheers.

Comment: Not sure why this obvious thing not working in Eclipse Neon ?

Comment: This should be top answer.

Comment: Great thank you, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 7):

For Project specific settings
In Project->Properties->C/C++ General:

- Tick Enable project specific Settings
- Select Doxygen as Documentation tool

Then typing `/**` above the function/method and hitting enter will work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14562109/2436175).