# Autogenerate C/C++ function comments in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, slickedit

This is a basically duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033190/autogenerate-function-comments-in-eclipse).
However, I'm looking for the same answer that will work in C/C++ - some easy way to add comments to the functions with descriptions of all of the parameters. It was really easy to do in SLickEdit - just press Ctrl+SHift+D. All the answers and methods for the aforementioned question were for Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Doxygen.

You can set it up as follows:

Window->Preferences->C/C++ ->Editor->"Documentation tool"

Here are more details:

[A doxygen eclipse plugIn automatically generating stub documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537542/a-doxygen-eclipse-plugin-with-automatic-code-completion)