# Auto generate comments (documentation) for functions in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse Juno with CDT. I have written a function in a cpp file and I want to add comments for the function. Does CDT supports Auto generate comments by  "typing /** then press enter"? In my case the auto generated comments are only as follows.

```
/**
 * 
 */
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590019/2436175), I even configured to use Doxygen support.Go to C/C++ -> Editors -> Documentation Tool Comments: Doxygen.

I still get the comments as mentioned above. How can I configure eclipse to add comments of my own style?

I changed comments even in Code templates. Go to C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code templates -> Comments. I changed Types, Fields, Methods. Still there is no luck for me.

Can someone assist me on this?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 10):

If you want the automated filling in of parameters etc, like Eclipse for Java does.

Open your project properties. Then C++ General. Then select Doxygen as your documentation tool. The type /** as you did to get the fully filled comment.

Comment: Does not work, only /* * */ are inserted.  Can you tell me if you have something in C/C++ - Code Style Code Templates - Methods ?

Comment: See also @Antonio's link to the generally working solution. That also does work and is even better since it holds for the entire workspace.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, since it usually works and there was no feedback about any specific problem of the user asking this question, I would like to point to the [generally working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590019/2436175).

Comment: HI, does also not work for me with choosing doygen. There is a C/C++ - Code Style - Code Templates section and there is /* * */ - that is all what gets inserted. Do you have something else there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to type it just above the function. It shall work. However not sure of the coding template.