# How to automatically generate function header comments in eclipse-cdt?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way I can automatically generate the function headers for a function in eclipse cdt ? I have seen related posts which ask to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> or type `/**` before function header and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However i am wondering if it is possible to get a predefined function header. I tried to define my format in

> C/C++ > Code style > Code templates > Comments > Methods

but could not find a way to use it in code.

Comment: And what exactly do you want them to contain?

Comment: basically any info I want... like function name, author, date, parameters, copyright notice.. etc

Comment: with a smell which doxygen can breath in.

Comment: similar(and not equal) unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592605/auto-generate-comments-for-functions-in-eclipse-cdt

Comment: Please comment if the question is not clear enough or if it is a known bug in eclipse

Answer (score 15):

I am afraid I have a partial answer for you:

1. If you go to -

- C/C++ -> Editor: "Documentation tool comments" -> "Workspace default": Doxygen

And type `/** + enter` this will fill in the comments with param & return tags automatically

I have found no way to add other fields automatically though

2. If you go to `windows -> preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Templates`, you will be able to create templates that eclipse will be able to auto-complete, when typing their name.
   For example, you can create a template called 'author', set the context to 'doc comment' and set the tag you need as a pattern. For this example, I used `@author ${user}` (note the use of a variable). Now you can start typing 'aut', press `ctrl+space` for auto-complete, and your tag will be inserted.

I understand this may not be the answer you are looking for, but it might help. I too have struggled with the eclipse settings to automatically generate these, but you *will* become very fast at doing this with templates, *and* you have more control over the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a little workaround.

Create a template in perferences >> C/C++ >> Editor >> Templates
Give unique Name (like comfun)
use the Variables like i did (${...}

save template

now enter the unique name INSIDE the function declaration and hit ctrl+space (watch out that no text is marked),
so eclipse can evaluate the Variables
All you have to do is move the auto generated text above the function.

I hope that helps a bit.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    F U N C T I O N   I N F O R M A T I O N                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  ToDo: check auto generated function comment                           |
|                                                                              |
|  Function Name:  ${enclosing_method}                                     |
|                                                                              |
|  Prototype at:   ${file_base}_tdf.h                                   |
|                                                                              |
|  Description:    add some useful content                                     |
|                                                                              |
|                                                                              |
|  Parameter:      ${enclosing_method_arguments}         |
|                                                                              |
|  Return Value:   ${return_type} OK               |
|                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```